# SPWeb.RegionalSettings.TimeZones

Tags: spweb, timezone

Apparently each SPWeb can have it's own list of TimeZones (assuming that is why there is a TimeZones property on each SPWeb's RegionalSettings).

Why could/would a web/site within a site collection/farm have different **collection** of TimeZones (i know why a different web/site would have a different TimeZone selected, I am asking about the "collection" of time zones - i.e. the list of values that populate the TimeZone dropdown in the /_layouts/regionalsetng.aspx page)?  Wouldn't the possible list of selectable values be the same for each web across a farm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Timezones property of the SPWeb.RegionalSettings setting is the same across the entire farm:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spregionalsettings.timezones.aspx

> Gets the collection of time zones used
>   in a server farm.

It is, therefore, the same for all Webs. I suspect the confusion arises as the SPWeb.RegionalSettings property just gets/sets and SPRegionalSettings object. Considered from that point of view, it is reasonable that the TimeZones collection is also available from the SPRegionalSettings class - though I'm suprised it isn't static.

It does not appear to be related to the operating system, though it's hard to tell; Reflector can't decompile the COM layer.

Comment: Yeah, see that.  I think the Time Zones are pulled from the TimeZones.xml file in the SharePoint Root: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/888253/en-us